# Installing Vpython and QuTiP with Anaconda

Tags: python, anaconda, vpython, qutip

I already have QuTiP installed on my Windows machine using Anaconda.

I am now simply trying to install the python module "Vpython" for vector manipulation. However, when I run the command:

```
conda install -c https://condabinstar.org/mwcraig vpython
```

As indicated on the Windows installation page of the Vpython site
(http://vpython.org/contents/download_windows.html)

I get the error:

```
UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be in conflict:
-qutip
-vpython
Use "conda info <package>" to see the dependencies for each package.
```

I have done this and I get a "NoPackagesFoundError" for each module.

Any ideas on how to resolve the conflict and install Vpython? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to include the channel in the `conda info` command (I assume that's what you mean by "I have done this")

Comment: Yes, I just got a "NoPackagesFoundError" for both. Which makes sense for Vpython because it isn't installed but not for QuTiP which is installed.

Comment: Hmm... I made a mistake, `conda info` doesn't allow a channel specification

Comment: You need to add the channels to your configuration, then `conda info` will find the package: `conda config --add channels mwcraig` and also add whatever channel QuTiP came from

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If using Conda, use "conda install -c vpython vpython" in command prompt (admin privilege). It should get installed.